# calling an external .js file from html file

Tags: javascript, html

my main.js looks like this

```
function myfunction(){
  alert("Button Pressed");
}
```

The HTML file

```
<head>
<title>meteorTest</title>
<script type="javascript" src="main.js">
</script>
<!--<script>
    function myfunction(){
        alert("hello");
    }
</script>-->
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction();" value="Click me!" />
</body>
```

If i run from the internal myfunction() it works fine. When I comment that out and run from the external .js I get this error:

"(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://localhost:3000/:1:1)"

Both the HTML and the .js are located in the same directory, so the path in src="main.js" should be right.

Comment: What's your project directory look like?

Comment: remove type="javascript" or use type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 0):

On the external script you currently have `type="javascript"` but you need `type="text/javascript"` in order for it to be evaluated.

Comment: getting the same error when I press the button. Also getting a new error now when the page initially loads saying: main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @HavocShot the script was loaded and evaluated and had a syntax error. You can start a new question about that if you wish.

Comment: @HavocShot you have "<script>" tag in your main.js, remove it

Answer (score -1):

Ok.. Analyzing your problem; give a try to button tag and JQuery click event.

1. Calling from button tag

> meteorTest
>
> ```
> <body>
> <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
> <button onclick="myfunction()" value="Click me!" ></button>
> </body>
> ```

2. jQuery Click Event (Note:- Do include jquery.js/ jquery.min.js file)

   > ```
   > <title>meteorTest</title>
   > <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
   > </script>
   > </head>
   >
   > <body>
   > <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
   > <button id="callme" value="Click me!" ></button>
   > </body>
   > ```

In Javascript side (main.js)

```
$("#callme").click(function(){
  myfunction();
});
```